# Array - Remove Duplicate/No Key

Tags: php, arrays

Trying to learn how to work with Arrays, merging (or removing duplicate).  Basically this: The database will have the actual data and I have another array that will give me all the result I expected to have.

**Database:**

`V1`, `V2`, `V5`, `V6`, `V7`, `V10`

**Custom Array:**

`V1`, `V2`, `V3`, `V4`, `V5`, `V6`, `V7`, `V8`, `V9`, `V10`

I would like to have the output to tell me:

`V3`, `V4`, `V8`, `V9`

But I keep getting only `V1` as the output. I must've missed some vital information somewhere.

**Example code I have:**

```
for($x = 0; $x < 1201; $x++){ $a[] = array('VFL'.$x); }
            $MFSQL = 'SELECT SCPlayer FROM SC'.$S;
                $MFSQL .= ' WHERE SCSnap = (SELECT MAX(DSSnap) FROM DataSnap WHERE DSServer = '.$S.')';
                $MFSQL .= ' AND (SCPlayer REGEXP "VFL[0-9]{1,4}")';
                $MFSQL .= ' ORDER BY SCPlayer';
            $Re = $ZD -> query($MFSQL);
            while($Ro = $ZD -> fetch_assoc($Re)){ $b[] = array($Ro['SCPlayer']); }
            $c = array_values(array_unique($a+$b));
            echo json_encode($c);
```

Any help/insight appreciated!

Comment: For me, your code is barely readable. It's not a good idea to name variables like that - names should be telling.

Comment: Why do you pack each string in one-element array here:
`$a[] = array('VFL'.$x);`
and here:
`$b[] = array($Ro['SCPlayer']);` ?

Why not 
`$a[] = 'VFL'.$x;`and `$b[] = $Ro['SCPlayer'];` ?

Comment: Now I learn something here. (this is a straight up hobby for me, always learning something new).  I always thought you need $a[] = array(something).  Can you explain the differences between both?

Comment: With `$a[] = ` a new element is added to array $a. 
With `array()` a new empty array is created (and returned).
And with `array($something)` a new array with one element equal to $something is created (and returned).

Comment: Ahh gotcha :) Many thanks and finally got the result I wanted with the change below and yours.  Again, many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
$arr_database = array("V1", "V2", "V5", "V6", "V7", "V10");
$arr_custom = array("V1", "V2", "V3", "V4", "V5", "V6", "V7", "V8", "V9", "V10");

$arr_output = array_diff($arr_custom, $arr_database);

print_r($arr_output);
```

**OUTPUT :**

```
Array
(
    [2] => V3
    [3] => V4
    [7] => V8
    [8] => V9
)
```

**[DEMO](http://3v4l.org/tJJQB)**

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I'm getting blank in output now.  Just as baffled at the moment.  I tested both $a and $b individually and both are showing result from custom/database.  But putting both together,  end result shows blank.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [array_diff](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php):

```
$arr = array_diff($custom, $database);
```